# Issue with iOS Login with Rails App + Devise

Tags: android, ios, ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a Rails app that I'm designing an iOS app for.  The Rails app uses Devise for user login.  When a user logs in through the mobile application, the Rails app should return an authentication token that then gets used throughout the app.

I already have a working Android app, and I followed the tutorial on this page to enable login through the Android app:

http://lucatironi.github.io/tutorial/2012/10/15/ruby_rails_android_app_authentication_devise_tutorial_part_one/

This is what my custom Devise SessionsController looks like:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token,
                     :if => Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }
warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#failure")
render :status => 200,
       :json => { :success => true,
                  :info => "Logged in",
                  :data => { :auth_token => current_user.authentication_token } }
end
end
```

This has always worked for my Android app.

But I'm having a bizarre problem with logging in using my iOS app.  Here is what I have for the login:

```
-(IBAction)authenticateUser {
    [keychainItem resetKeychainItem]; // remove any existing auth_token

    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:sessionsBaseURL];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSDictionary * userDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: [_txtUsername text], @"username", [_txtPassword text], @"password", nil];
    NSDictionary * holderDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: userDict, @"user", nil];
    NSLog(@"holderDict: %@", holderDict);
    NSData * holder = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:holderDict options:0 error:&error];

    NSLog(@"auth_token%@", [keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrType)]);
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:holder];

    NSURLResponse * response = nil;
    NSData * receivedData = nil;

    receivedData = [NSMutableData data];
    receivedData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSLog(@"attempting login");

    // get dictionary from json data
    NSDictionary * jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization
                                   JSONObjectWithData: receivedData
                                   options:kNilOptions
                                   error:&error];
    if(error == nil){
        NSLog(@"successful login");
        [keychainItem setObject:[_txtUsername text] forKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrAccount)];
        NSLog(@"jsonResponse: %@", jsonResponse);
        NSDictionary * dataResponse = [jsonResponse objectForKey:@"data"];
        auth_token = [dataResponse objectForKey:@"auth_token"];
        // save user authentication token
       [keychainItem setObject:auth_token forKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)];
    }else{
        NSLog(@"jsonResponse: %@", jsonResponse);
    }
    NSLog(@"error: %@" , [error localizedDescription]);

    [self checkLoginApproved];
}
```

The user is able to login correctly the first time, and the correct authentication token is returned.  However, if the user logs out and then logs back in using an incorrect password on the iOS app, the Rails app seems to think the user has logged in correctly (it doesn't return an unauthorized, and it returns a null authentication token).

This leads me to believe something is wrong with warden.authenticate.  It's been very difficult for me to isolate where this problem is, in the Rails app or the iOS app.

Does anyone have an example of getting their iOS app to work with Rails and devise for user login?  Or does anyone have other ideas for why what I have isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

Hello StackOverflow World.

It ended up being an issue mostly with warden.authenticate as I expected.  I ended up writing a custom method for determining whether the user's login credentials are valid (Rails):

```
def create
    user = User.find_for_authentication(:username=>params[:user][:username])
    if user && user.valid_password?(params[:user][:password])
      # generate token if it doesn't exist
      if user.authentication_token.blank?
          Rails.logger.debug "generating authentication token for #{user.username} #{user.id}"
          new_token = generate_authentication_token
          Rails.logger.debug "new authentication token: #{new_token}"
          user.update_column("authentication_token", new_token)
      end

       render :status => 200,
           :json => { :success => true,
                      :info => "Logged in",
                      :data => { :auth_token => user.authentication_token } }
        Rails.logger.debug "current user: #{current_user.username} #{current_user.id}"
        Rails.logger.debug "current user authentication_token: #{current_user.authentication_token}"
    else
        render :status => 401,
         :json => { :success => false,
                    :info => "Login Failed",
                    :data => {} }
    end

 def generate_authentication_token
    loop do
      token = Devise.friendly_token
      break token unless User.where(authentication_token: token).first
    end
  end
```

This is what I have in my iOS for logging in:

```
-(IBAction)authenticateUser {
    [keychainItem resetKeychainItem]; // remove any existing auth_token

    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:sessionsBaseURL];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSDictionary * userDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: [_txtUsername text], @"username", [_txtPassword text], @"password", nil];
    NSDictionary * holderDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: userDict, @"user", nil];
    NSLog(@"holderDict: %@", holderDict);
    NSData * holder = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:holderDict options:0 error:&error];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:holder];

    NSURLResponse * response = nil;
    NSData * receivedData = nil;

    receivedData = [NSMutableData data];
    receivedData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
//    NSLog(@"attempting login");

    // get dictionary from json data
    NSDictionary * jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization
                                   JSONObjectWithData: receivedData
                                   options:kNilOptions
                                   error:&error];

    NSLog(@"jsonResponse: %@", jsonResponse);

    if( [[jsonResponse objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"auth_token"] ) {
        NSLog(@"saving login");
        NSDictionary * dataResponse = [jsonResponse objectForKey:@"data"];
        auth_token = [dataResponse objectForKey:@"auth_token"];
        [keychainItem setObject:[_txtUsername text] forKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrAccount)];
        // save user authentication token
        [keychainItem setObject:auth_token forKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrType)];
    }

    [self checkLoginApproved];
}
```

and Logging out:

```
NSString *logoutURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:[sessionsBaseURL stringByAppendingFormat:@"?auth_token=%@", auth_token]];
    NSLog(@"logoutURLString: %@", logoutURLString);


    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:logoutURLString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"DELETE"];

    // receive JSON response
    NSURLResponse * response = nil;
    NSData * receivedData = nil;

    NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];

    receivedData = [NSMutableData data];
    receivedData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [self.keychainItem resetKeychainItem];
```

I wasn't able to find any examples like this, so I hope this helps someone else.